# how to remove few first positions from binary file

Tags: c#, file, binary, byte

I've used an HEX editor to figure out that a encrypting made to a .WAV file is adding 16 blocks of empty 00's.
I understood that the first 64 positions should be deleted and then the file is de-crypted.
After searching the site i couldn't find an example that will match my case,
I just need to open the file and write it to another file without those first 64 positions.
Appreciate your help

Comment: Hmmm so your question would imply that the WAVE data is not encrypted but only the header data? Do you know what format this WAVE data is in? According to me, it isn't the best encryption for WAVE files then. The header chunk contains details about the sample rate, bitsizes of the chunks, etc., but it is also depending on what type of wave file that has been used. If it is indeed enough to skip the first 64 bytes of data, a binary reader would be enough to use to skip the first 64 bytes like Aik explained below.

Answer (score -1):

If you use 64byte buffer to copy the file, than you can skip the first one:

```
using(var originalFile = File.OpenRead("some file"))
using(var newFile = File.OpenWrite("some file"))
{

byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

    int readBytes= 0;
    int currentReaded = 0;
    do
    {
        currentReaded = originalFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        readBytes += currentReaded; 

        if(readBytes > 64)
        {
            newFile.Write(buffer, 0, currentReaded);
        }

    } while (currentReaded == buffer.Length);
}
```